# Why does my JIRA report say: "Open issue moved out of board (into an unmapped status)"?

Tags: jira

I have a project with extensive workflows set up, and the the tickets are moving smoothly through the entire workflow. But here is a strange behavior that I'm seeing:

Whenever I move a Ticket from "In progress" status to the "Needs Review" Status, the sprint Report says that it has been moved out.

Similarly on the Burndown chart it shows that this Ticket has been burned with the status:

> Open issue moved out of board (into an unmapped status)

I have made sure that the "Needs Review" status has been mapped to the "In Progress" category.

How do I solve this, and get the correct burndown?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to understand that any report on a  JIRA board, is at the end of the day, a report on the board as it is configured.

You will find that this particular status is not present on any column in the Kanban board, which is why you are getting this message.

Once you properly map this status to a column, the error will go away.

Comment: Hi Devdatta. Welcome to PMSE. If you resolved this question yourself can you mark this as your accepted answer and add a comment or edit to the answer to clarify that you worked out the answer.

Comment: @willl I need to wait for atleast two days before I can accept my own answer. Its probably because I don't have enough rep on this site

Comment: Ah, my mistake. I didn't realise that.

Answer (score 0):

when on your board do the following:

1. Click Board > Configure
2. on the left side column click "Columns"
3. where you have unmapped statuses you can map these to the correct columns this will fix your issues

Thanks
Ash